# How to make repeat notification with stackdriver

Tags: notifications, alert, monitoring, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

using stackdriver's url monitoring.
When it goes down, one time will come but the next will not come.

I would like you to repeatedly notify this if the situation does not change in the next 5 minutes, but I do not know the setting.
somebody help!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLROH.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a product manager with Stackdriver.  This is a feature request that we have heard before and are aware of.

This is, unfortunately, not supported at this time, though there are some workarounds:

- PagerDuty can be used as a notification channel, and PagerDuty supports repeated notifications.
- Webhook can be used as a notification channel, which can be used to create a fully custom delivery mechanism (including one that delivers repeatedly).

Sorry that this isn't available more simply. Hope this helps.

Comment: Just to chime in, in case you're still the Stackdriver PM, I would love to see the ability to repeat notifications while the issue is open. We've had some slip through the cracks since the notification only happened once.

Comment: Here is a message from 2020: Repeating notifications would be awesome right about now! Thanks!